# No data appearing when I attempt to scrape data from a table

Tags: python, selenium, beautifulsoup, screen-scraping

I'm attempting to scrape data off of table of data on a website, but when I run my code the output is just blank. I'm not sure why nothing is getting printed. Is the content getting scraped too large for the IDE terminal? Or is their a fundemental issue with my code?

Note: the website link is: https://www.kaggle.com/nareshbhat/health-care-data-set-on-heart-attack-possibility

And the data im trying to scrape is the table at the bottom (heart.csv)

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Code:

```
import time

import pandas as pd

from selenium import webdriver

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

import re

 
DRIVER_PATH = r"/Users/mouradsal/Downloads/DataSets Python/chromedriver"

URL = "https://www.kaggle.com/nareshbhat/health-care-data-set-on-heart-attack-possibility"


browser = webdriver.Chrome(DRIVER_PATH)

browser.get(URL)

time.sleep(4)

content = browser.find_elements_by_css_selector(".dfXZEj div")


for e in content:

        start = e.get_attribute("innerHTML")

        soup= BeautifulSoup(start, features=("lxml"))
        
        print(soup.get_text())
```

Thanks

Comment: Do you need to sign-in first?

Comment: Try just using print(e.text) .In the loop.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved the above question using Java code and it is working fine for me.

Attaching the Java code for more information and as per my understanding in Python you can directly use

`start = e.text`

Java Code

```
    WebDriverManager.chromedriver().setup();
    WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
    
    driver.get("https://www.kaggle.com/nareshbhat/health-care-data-set-on-heart-attack-possibility");
    
    List<WebElement> list = driver.findElements(By.cssSelector(".dfXZEj div"));
    
    System.out.println(list.size());
    
    for(WebElement element : list) {
        System.out.println(element.getText());
    }
    
    driver.quit();
```

Comment: any way you could re-write that with Python code?

Answer (score 0):

```
for e in content:
   print(e.text)
```

you don't need to use beautifulsoup